# I can't connect to my router when I change wlan0 mac address on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I can't connect to my router when I change `wlan0` MAC address on Ubuntu 14.04

I change the title using

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
ifconfig wlan0 hw ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Change succeeded but connection no longer succeeds.

I also tried using `macchanger`; I got the same result.

Comment: It could help if you describe what you are trying to achieve. Changing a MAC address is seldom a goal in itself. If you are testing MAC address filtering on your router, this would be intended behaviour.

Comment: Target experiments to perfect the deal with the network using Ubuntu
Note: that I carried out the method mentioned with distribution kali and it succeeded, and remained the problem with Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

This *does* look suspiciously like MAC filtering. Are you sure that with Kali it works (i.e. MAC changed and WiFi connection operating reliably)?

If Kali works with a different MAC, then we may be sure that there is no MAC filtering in operation. Therefore there's something fishy in Ubuntu.

Possibly, the MAC field is used *somewhere* and changing it only at the WLAN level is not enough (or rather, it starts a conflict in that "somewhere").

Good candidates for this mysterious somewhere (that Ubuntu has, and Kali apparently has not) are:

- the networking scripts. Try doing a network restart after the MAC change.
- the DHCP layer. It should be part of the networking scripts, so try restarting *this* service first. If it does not work, *then* try with the whole kaboodle of `/etc/init.d/networking restart` (or `restart networking` - sorry; I can never remember the syntax between the different distros, and I am a OpenSuSE fan).
- from cold steel: try using the `hwaddress` option in `interfaces` and **reboot**. You can't do this "on the fly" every time of course, but maybe it's enough for your purposes.